# Adding executable files to my PATH in a Linux shell

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, environment-variables, path

My goal is to run the R file helloworld.r from my home directory using Rscript in a Linux shell. My helloworld.r file looks like this

```
#!/home/usr/env Rscript
print("Hello World")
```

I have added `export PATH="$PATH:/home/usr/R-3.5.1/bin/"` to my path. Now when I run

`Rscript helloworld.r`

from my home directory I get

`Fatal error: cannot open 'helloworld.r': No such file or directory`

Is this because of the code or because I haven't successfully added this to my PATH? (Or neither?)

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "from my home directory", are you talking about what directory *you* are in, or what directory *the script* (i.e. helloworld.r) is in? Also, where is the `Rscript` interpreter itself?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are misunderstanding how `PATH` is searched. It only is searched for the command/program, NOT the options being passed to it. Therefore `Rscript` in your example is being searched for (and found) in `PATH`, but not `helloworld.r`, because it is an option passed to `Rscript`.

Now, for the solution:
`chmod +x helloworld.r` from the directory it is in, to make it executable.
Your first line in `helloworld.r` starting with `#!` is correct, and now it will work if you run it as `helloworld.r` without the `Rscript` in front of it.

About the `#!`: That is for when you run a file as a command without specifying the interpreter, such as `Rscript`. Linux checks for that line to tell it what interpreter to use.

**EDIT**
To make sure your `#!` line is correct, run `helloworld.r` from its directory as `./hellworld.r`. If that works, your `#!` is correct. And I misread what you are setting your `PATH` to. Your `PATH` needs to be set (in this case) to both your `Rscript` interpreter, *and* the path of `helloworld.r`.

Comment: I don't think that "#!/home/usr/env Rscript" is correct (as you state)..  Shouldn't it be (for his example) "#!/home/usr/R-3.5.1/bin/RScript".  Also after he does this (and the other things you mention), he will need to add the directory to launch it .. as in "./helloworld.r".. am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I received the same error message. I went to my directory where the file was located and entered the following command prompt ```chmod -x helloworld.r ```. I then went back to my home directory and tried executing the file and received the same error message back again.

Comment: @Ctat41 See my edits.

Comment: @CMasMas: `/home/usr/env` is probably wrong... but `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` would be correct, as it's a commonly used method to apply $PATH lookup for the "Rscript" interpreter itself.